# Образование сложных прилагательных/причастий, их семантические различия

Tags: словообразование, семантика

Взять за пример слова "благо" и "расположение".
В первое варианте образуем "благорасположенный" - т.е. расположенный благожелательно, положительно.
Во втором варианте образуем "благорасположительный" - (причём сразу выдаёт слово за ошибку, хотя по-факту оным не является, в виде подтверждения - http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/02/sl204607.htm), по-сути смысл тот же, но слову придаётся некий оттенок личного действия по отношению к объекту (кому/чему-либо).
Другой случай, слово "сатана".
"Осатанелый" - ассоциация уже "давно" (завершенное состояние).
"Осатаневший" - образ - "только что" ("когда" , "из-за чего").
И образуя схожие по тематике, можно ли сказать: "обесневший" ? "обесновавшийся" ?
В общем, есть ли какие-то общие правила на этот счёт?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Прилагательные обозначают постоянный во времени признак, в них используются суффиксы, характерные для прилагательного: благлрасположИТЕЛЬНый, осатанеЛый.

Причастия обозначают признак, соотнесенный со временем: осатаневший (завершение действия к данному моменту); благорасположенный (настроенный положительно к данному моменту).

Глаголов обеснеть и обесноваться нет, есть глагол бесноваться (от гнева, ярости), соответственно, нет таких причастий.

Прилагательные в данной тематике: осатанелый, бесноватый (суффикс прилагательного ОВАТ).